# Find bounty questions for specific tags

Tags: support, search, bounties, unanswered-questions

I want to know if there is some way to check unanswered questions that have bounties with a specific tag? For example if I want to check unanswered questions with bounties tagged C# or ASP.NET. If there is some way please tell me and if not is it possible to have this feature?

Answer (score 4):

Go to the tag page and click on 'Featured' tab.

For example, on [C# tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) click on [Featured tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=featured), it will show C# question having bounties.

Currently there is no search option to filter bounty questions only. For example, `bounty:1` or `hasbounty:yes` is not supported in the search box. If you want to find unanswered questions that have a bounty on it, the closest you can go is to use `[c#] answers:0 hasnotice:1` in the search box.

Comment: I checked it and this is what i wanted but i forgot one thing to mention in my question that i want to check unanswered questions with bounties of specific tag.Please see the question now.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if the Search Fu had a switch for that, like:

```
[regex] featured:yes
```

Or even better:

```
[regex] bounty:1
[regex] bounty:500
```

(`1` for any bounty, `500` for a bounty worth at least 500).

The search window on the top right should then show this string rather than just `[regex]` on the [featured tab of the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex?sort=featured&pageSize=15).